# Javafx showing folder icons when I run it

Tags: eclipse, javafx-8

Im having this problem running javafx on my mac its opening a folder icon named java everytime im running it. Is there a solution for this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXtsh.png)

I tried the run configuration with --module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-21/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml  and installed JavaFX from eclipse marketplace and followed up javafx documentation to install it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmY0L.png)

Comment: Please provide some details like code or snippet

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You neither need nor should set VM arguments in the launch configuration. You also do not need anything from the Eclipse Marketplace (JavaFX is a dependency for your application, not something that can be installed via the Marketplace; maybe you mean e(fx)clipse). Just follow the [documentation on openjfx.io: _JavaFX and Eclipse_](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).